# Can I say "subscribe by Facebook/Twitter"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, internet

I have a website. I have 5 subscription options in my site.

As of now my titles displayed like this:

1. subscribe by email
2. subscribe by rss
3. subscribe using facebook
4. subscribe using twitter
5. subscribe using googleplus

My 3, 4, and 5 instructions look a little too long. Can I use the preposition "by" instead of "using"?

For example: *subscribe by facebook*, *subscribe by twitter*, and *subscribe by googleplus*.

Comment: Why not just precede your list of options with some "shared" text such as *"Select your preferred subscription method"*, then just call them *email, rss, facebook, twitter, googleplus*?

Comment: Also, there's always _via_.

Comment: Note that _subscribe_ is not the usual word to use for those platforms. You _follow_ someone _on_ Twitter, you _add_ (or _like_, depending on what you're looking for people to do exactly) someone _on_ Facebook, and you _add_ (or _+1_) someone on Google+. Neither platform offers any kind of subscription, so using _subscribe_ seems quite misguided to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following FumbleFingers rewording suggestion would be the most sensible thing to do.  But let me address your «*Can I use "by" instead of "using"*» question: While use of *by* would not break any rules of grammar or meaning and would be commonly understood, I would not choose to use it in the way your examples show.  I regard "subscribe using twitter" and "subscribe via twitter" as acceptable and nearly equivalent, but "subscribe by twitter" as awkward. *([Via](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/via)* has senses as a preposition of "by way of" and "by means of").